# What is a Pact of Secrecy? Also, what is a Pact of Cooperation?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization 5, one of the diplomatic options is a Pact of Secrecy. You sign it with one civilization against a specific other civilization.

There's another called a Pact of Cooperation, which you sign with just the other civilization.

However, I can't find any mention of either of these pacts in the manual or in the Civilpedia.

**What do they do?**

*Edit:* Added Pact of Cooperation, since its in the same boat and we have that answered too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both the *Pact of Secrecy* and *Pact of Cooperation* have been removed from newer versions of the game.

Since version **[1.0.1.135](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?89117-Patch-Notes)** (15th December 2010) they have been approximately replaced with the **Declaration of Friendship** and **Denounce**, which have a similar meaning behind them, but are both now public and have more visible diplomatic repercussions.

Since version **1.0.1.217** (1st March 2011) both of these also expire after 50 turns.

---

Being a **friend** with another nation has the following effects:

- Your relationship with the nation is improved (*I think so, anyway*).
- The friend nation may occasionally request aid (eg, gold, luxury resource, etc) - if you refuse, there is a long term negative effect on your relationship.
- If you befriend a nation, this will often have a positive effect on your relationships with other nations who are friends with the nation you befriend.
- If you befriend a nation, this will often have a negative effect on your relationships with other nations who dislike the nation you befriend.

Groups of nations that are all friends with one another can effectively form a sort of unofficial alliance, and it can be powerful to be within a group of this nature. Similarly, be wary of attacking/upsetting a nation in a group, because you might find they drag all their allies in to the fight against you.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a [quote](http://forums.2kgames.com/forums/showpost.php?p=1137072&postcount=9) from one of the game's producers

> A Pact of Cooperation will get you
>   better deals with that AI player
>   provided that you reciprocate. It's an
>   option meant to foster a positive
>   relationship. Likewise, a Pact of
>   Secrecy (where the AI asks you to work
>   against another Civ) will also build a
>   better relationship, provided you
>   actually follow through, and do not
>   cooporate with the target Civ.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than it doing nothing.

Comment: "... provided you actually follow through, and do not cooporate with the target Civ" - Could you elaborate a bit? What actions are viewed as actions that "cooperate" with another civilization?

Comment: I assume that would include trading with them, accepting a research agreement or pact with them, or giving them open borders.  I don't think you're penalized for existing agreements with that civ since you can't cancel them prematurely (without declaring war).